# can someone help finding whats wrong on this code of finding the median of 2 sorted arrays

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, function, median

its giving an error of heap buffer overflow.
the question is to find the median of two sorted arrays.

```
double findMedianSortedArrays(int* nums1, int nums1Size, int* nums2, int nums2Size){
    int n = nums1Size, m = nums2Size;
    double med1, med2, median;
    if(n % 2 == 1){
        med1 = (nums1[(n / 2) - 1] + nums1[n / 2]) / 2;
    }
    else{
        med1 = nums1[((n + 1) / 2) - 1];
    }
    if(m%2 == 1){
        med2 = (nums2[(m / 2) - 1] + nums2[(m / 2)]) / 2;
    }
    else{
        med2 = nums2[((m + 1) / 2) - 1];
    }
    median = (med1 + med2) / 2;
    return median;
}
```

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: RobertS is onto the correct question.  I just ran your function with several different inputs.  I didn't have any issues with memory.  Can you post the entire program? You are probably mishandling your array inputs or sizes.

Comment: @PatrickOfThings That´s exactly what I am up to, too.

Comment: The median of two sorted arrays is not the average of both medians, but the median of both arrays merged.

Comment: Take a look at this example: 
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
array2 = [100,200,300,400]
The median of these two arrays is 5.

What will your code return?